# Accurate wall thickness measurement in Blender?

Tags: 3d-printing, measurement

I have some detailed models I have managed to successfully print at larger scales (20-30cm max height), however the wall thickness in many areas is very thin and when scaled down to much smaller sizes (<15cm) the wall thickness drops below the 0.5mm minimum required by my manufacturer.

I appear to be getting varied and unclear results using the measurement tool in Blender to measure wall thickness after applying a Solidify modifier. Even when applying the 0.5mm thickness the measurement tool is returning <0.5mm thicknesses.

Is there a better way? Ideally I am looking to see a minimum wall thickness for the entire model as a baseline, so then I can perhaps apply Solidify modifier to only specific vertex groups to bump up the wall thickness only in certain problem areas.

Comment: the values will be wrong in edit mode if you have not applied scale in object mode.  Is that your problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I don't think so. I've applied scale and still getting <0.5mm thickness with both measurement tool and thickness checker in the 3D printing tool panel